# HTML5 Responsive one page site with php variables in url

Tags: php, html, variables, hyperlink

I have just built a responsive HTML5 page, and as such, it links to other parts of the page from the menu... so, I have `#home`, `#about`, etc. I also need to pass a php variable for language, so that the correct language displays on the page, so I have `lang=es`, `lang=gb`, etc.

The languages are working fine and the links are working fine, but when I combine them both, the links stop working. Either as `#about?lang=es` or as `index.php#about?lang=es`. Neither works. It just stays at the top of the page and doesn't jump.

Any clues as to why?

Thanks in advance.
Kirsty

Comment: please add some minimal code for others to debug - thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass the php params first and then html tag ID 
see the example below 
`https://domain.extension?lang=es#about`

Dont worry about php variable value, it will remain untouched, servers will handle it